# Dropdown menu does not work correctly. (html)

Tags: javascript, html, css

im making my website just using html code (with no bootstrap). I want to make a Dropdown List with a list of specs. The problem is once it is done when i open my List - the content which is going below does not move more below so it overlaps on the List.. Look at this picture to see what i have. [image]

The ideal idea is to make the following: [image]

So here when i open the List the below contet gose more below automatically (But this is bootstrap so i can not just copy that because i am using only html)

My html code is this:

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
  <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#home">Home</a>
    <a href="#about">About</a>
    <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

And css :

```
.dropbtn {
  background-color: #3498DB;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.dropbtn:hover, .dropbtn:focus {
  background-color: #2980B9;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  min-width: 160px;
  overflow: auto;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown a:hover {background-color: #ddd;}

.show {display: block;}
```

And javascript:

```
<script>

function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

// Close the dropdown if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Try to remove `position: absolute;` from `.dropdown-content` class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VNojBe

1. Remove `position: absolute;` from `.dropdown-content`
2. Change to `position: relative` in `.dropdown-content`